# DataContract serialization throw an Security exception

Tags: serialization, windows-phone-7, datacontractserializer, securityexception

I am trying to use DataContractSerialization on WPF and WP7. All things are good on WPF but not on WP7. When I tryed to serialize an object on wp7, I received an unknown security exception. Please view the attached source code and help me.
[image: Capture]

[Source code (mediafire)](http://www.mediafire.com/?gamybdgotp02mne)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

In my scenario, I was trying to serialize a nested class.

I had to remove the nesting and define the class as public, and then it worked.